# Pulling one record per id by record type sql

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and I'm trying to write a query to do the following.

I have a table containing records types and IDs.  You can have duplicate and multiple types per ID.

```
Type              ID
History            1
History            1
Geography          1
Geography          2
French             2
French             3
English            3
English            4 
History            4
History            4
```

I want to create one record per ID with a 'Type Hierarchy' of History, Geography, All Others.  So in the above example, I am looking for the following:

```
History   1
Geography 2
French    3
History   4
```

In other words give me all history records, if an ID does not have history give me the geography records, and for the IDs without either give me one of any record type.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: you have `History` listed twice is that an error? There is also no `English`?

Comment: No it isn't an error.  There can be types and ids that are the same with different begin/end dates (which I didn't list in the table)

Comment: Are the dates used to determine which type to select? If so, then you should include those because how do you decide which `history` record to select?

Comment: Maybe I am not explaining this well.  I want one of each ID (1,2,3,4).  BUT the record I want to pull is based on the type.  If there is a History record, then I want this one, if not then pull the Geography record, otherwise if no History or Geography, then pull any other record.

Comment: The date is only relevant if the end date it is not null, but there can be multiple records with 'open' end dates and the other info on the record really isn't relevant. I will then use this query to join to other tables to pull info, so either history record would do as long as it is history and not english.

Comment: Please check the replies and mark the one as that suits your needs as the answer, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't tell your RDMS but the following code works for Oracle (and SQL Server, I suppose). For others, there are emulations for **`row_number`** function.

```
--creating table..

CREATE TABLE "YOURTABLE" 
(   "TIP" VARCHAR2(20), 
"IDE" NUMBER
) 

--inserting experimental values..

insert into YOURTABLE (TIP, IDE)
values ('History', 1);
insert into YOURTABLE (TIP, IDE)
values ('History', 1);    
insert into YOURTABLE (TIP, IDE)
values ('Geography', 1);    
insert into YOURTABLE (TIP, IDE)
values ('Geography', 2);    
insert into YOURTABLE (TIP, IDE)
values ('French', 2);    
insert into YOURTABLE (TIP, IDE)
values ('French', 3);    
insert into YOURTABLE (TIP, IDE)
values ('English', 3);    
insert into YOURTABLE (TIP, IDE)
values ('English', 4);    
insert into YOURTABLE (TIP, IDE)
values ('History', 4);    
insert into YOURTABLE (TIP, IDE)
values ('History', 4);

 --code..

select m.*
      from (select *
              from YOURTABLE
             where tip = 'History'
            union
            select *
              from YOURTABLE
             where tip = 'Geography'
               and ide not in (select ide from YOURTABLE where tip = 'History')
            union
            select tip, ide
              from (select s.*,
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ide ORDER BY ide) ord
                      from YOURTABLE s
                     where tip not in ('History', 'Geography')
                       and ide not in
                           (select ide
                              from YOURTABLE
                             where tip in ('History', 'Geography')))
             where ord = 1) m
```

Resulting table:

```
TIP                         IDE
-------------------- ----------
History                       1
Geography                     2
English                       3
History                       4
```

You said:

> 'Type Hierarchy' of History, Geography, All Others

In my example English got into the result, not French, but this shouldn't be a problem as "all others" are created equal.

Comment: Thank-you!!! I think I also figured this out by separating my queries and then joining them together, but your solution seems more compact and might run faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think something along the lines of

```
SELECT Type, ID
GROUP BY Type, ID
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks. But I am trying to only extract one record per ID based on the record type - in a hierarchy form. I could easily do this with traditional code at my previous job, but don't know the syntax in SQL